# Codeigniter deleting files in a directory not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, delete-file

I am trying to delete pdf files from a folder. I have written the delete_files function as follows

```
public function delete_files($company_id)
    {
        $this->load->model('search_model');

        $company = $this->search_model->get_company($company_id);
        $username  = $company[0]['username'];
    $path=$this->config->base_url('/uploads/'.$username . '/' . 'uploaded');
    $this->load->helper("file"); // load the helper
    delete_files($path, true); // delete all files/folders
    }
```

when i did `echo $path;` it shows the right path where i want the files deleted but when i run the entire function nothing happens and i just get a white screen.

Comment: You need to delete system file, not URL. Try with `$path = FCPATH . "uploads/$username/uploaded";`

Comment: Yup that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use path to file and not resource locator.

```
$path = FCPATH . "uploads/$username/uploaded";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

Use

```
$path = FCPATH . "uploads/$username/uploaded";
unset($path);
```